# Spring boot setResultTransformer and addScalar

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have problem on returning query result set using entityManager object .
I want to return my join query which should convert into pojo object.

so after many tries I found the below working code

```
public List<Test> getData() {

    Query a = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select t1.data1,t2.data2 from test1 t1 join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id");          
    a.unwrap(SQLQuery.class)      
    .addScalar("data1", LongType.INSTANCE)      
    .addScalar("data2", DoubleType.INSTANCE)      
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Test.class));     

    return a.getResultList();    
}
```

But I had warnings that `setResultTransformer()` and `addScalar()` methods are  deprecated.
Can any one please put the alternative code of it or please provide the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Please specify exactly the warning and what is deprecated.

Comment: setResultTransformer and addScalar are showing deprecated @davidxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The first thing deprecated is [`SQLQuery`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/) :

> (since 5.2) use `NativeQuery` instead.

2) But it will not solve your issue because [`SQLQuery.addScalar()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addScalar-java.lang.String-org.hibernate.type.Type-) [`org.hibernate.query.Query.setResultTransformer()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setResultTransformer-org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer-) are also deprecated as you noticed.
[From the Hibernate 5.3 migration guide](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Hibernate_5.3_Migration_Guide#org.hibernate.query.Query.setResultTransformer.28.29) :

> With a ResultTransformer it is possible to define how the results of a
>   query should be handled, i.e., it can be used to change the "shape" of
>   the query results.
>
> In Hibernate 6.0, the ResultTransformer will be replaced by a
>   @FunctionalInterface and for this reason, the setResultTransformer()
>   method in org.hibernate.query.Query is deprecated.
>
> There is no replacement for ResultTransformer in Hibernate 5.3,
>   therefore as recommended here, for the moment it can be used as-is.

So you can leave it such as and suppress the warning by adding also a `TODO` comment.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public List<Test> getData() {

    Query a = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
            "select t1.data1,t2.data2 >from test1 t1 join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id");
    a.unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
      // TODO warning to remove with Hibernate 6 for addScalar()
     .addScalar("data1", LongType.INSTANCE)
     .addScalar("data2", DoubleType.INSTANCE)
      // TODO warning to remove with Hibernate 6 for setResultTransformer()
     .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Test.class));

    return a.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you david and I changed SQLQuery.class to org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class and as you said i will make it as it is until hibernate updates comes for it (@FunctionalInterface).

Comment: i added @SuppressWarnings( {"deprecation"}) is that fine ?

Comment: It seems to be a good thing. Rather surprising to deprecate a method without giving any alternative. But well :) You are welcome. It is also good. But just the array is not required to specify the annotation `value()` when you defines a single value

Comment: How to convert this to hibernate stored procedure. I tried but i couldn’t use unwrap and scalar and setResultTransformer. The stored procedure of hibernate doest have properties of native query class. Can you explain it or give solution for it.

Comment: It is another issue. One question by issue to make it reusable for other users. So you should open a new question for that.

Comment: yes. you are right!. I created a new question.please have a look.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278326/how-to-use-hibernate-stored-procedure-with-setresulttransformer-and-scalar